# import module from socket error python

Tags: python, sockets

when i try to create af socket with the import socket module like:

```
from socket import *
from thread import *
responseok = bytes('ok')
HOST = ''
PORT = 4445
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c.bind((HOST, PORT))
c.listen(10)

def clientthread(conn):

   dat = conn.recv(1024)
   data = str(dat)
   print data
   conn.close()


while 1:
conn, addr = c.accept()
start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

c.close()
```

i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MikeClaudi\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\server2\src\socket.py", line 6, in    <module>
from socket import *
  File "C:\Users\MikeClaudi\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\server2\src\socket.py", line 11, in <module>
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

NameError: name 'socket' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
from socket import *
```

then you have to do

```
c = socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

But in order to not confuse the two `socket` (module and class), just

```
import socket
```

and then

```
c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```